# Rescaling environment

Tags: environments, scaling, puzzle

I'm creating a crossword puzzle using the `cwpuzzle` package (http://www.gerd-neugebauer.de/software/TeX/cwpuzzle/en/).

I need the solution to be displayed in a much smaller format (say, 50% the original size).

I tried to use `scalebox`:

```
\scalebox{.5}{
\begin{Puzzle}{5}{5}%
|[][Sf]S|[][Sf]A|[][Sf]T|[][Sf]O|[][Sf]R|.
|[][Sf]A|[][Sf]R|[][Sf]E|[][Sf]P|[][Sf]O|.
|[][Sf]T|[][Sf]E|[][Sf]N|[][Sf]E|[][Sf]T|.
|[][Sf]O|[][Sf]P|[][Sf]E|[][Sf]R|[][Sf]A|.
|[][Sf]R|[][Sf]O|[][Sf]T|[][Sf]A|[][Sf]S|.
\end{Puzzle}
}
```

However, this does not produce the desired effect, as, instead of the puzzle, one basically sees a sequence of internal `cwpuzzle` options.

What is the proper way to rescale the puzzle to a smaller size?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See **REVISION** below, added after answer accepted.

You need to set the puzzle in a `\vbox`.  Of course, then, if you wish to treat it as a horizontal object, the only way to control the width is to set the `\vbox` inside a `minipage`.

With this combination, one can, for example, place the reduced size puzzle in the upper left, as if it were an `\hbox`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{cwpuzzle,graphicx}
\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{minipage}{.7in}
\setbox0=\vbox{
\begin{Puzzle}{5}{5}%
|[][Sf]S|[][Sf]A|[][Sf]T|[][Sf]O|[][Sf]R|.
|[][Sf]A|[][Sf]R|[][Sf]E|[][Sf]P|[][Sf]O|.
|[][Sf]T|[][Sf]E|[][Sf]N|[][Sf]E|[][Sf]T|.
|[][Sf]O|[][Sf]P|[][Sf]E|[][Sf]R|[][Sf]A|.
|[][Sf]R|[][Sf]O|[][Sf]T|[][Sf]A|[][Sf]S|.
\end{Puzzle}
}
\scalebox{.5}{\copy0}
\end{minipage}
Normal text
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**REVISION:**

egreg asks why `\vbox` and `minipage`.  My initial attempts with `\hbox` failed and so I resorted to the `\vbox` approach above.  However, I must have erred in my original approach.  Here, an `\hbox` approach works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{cwpuzzle,graphicx}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\setbox0=\hbox{%
\begin{Puzzle}{5}{5}%
|[][Sf]S|[][Sf]A|[][Sf]T|[][Sf]O|[][Sf]R|.
|[][Sf]A|[][Sf]R|[][Sf]E|[][Sf]P|[][Sf]O|.
|[][Sf]T|[][Sf]E|[][Sf]N|[][Sf]E|[][Sf]T|.
|[][Sf]O|[][Sf]P|[][Sf]E|[][Sf]R|[][Sf]A|.
|[][Sf]R|[][Sf]O|[][Sf]T|[][Sf]A|[][Sf]S|.
\end{Puzzle}
}%
\scalebox{.5}{\copy0}
Normal text
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why `\vbox` and the `minipage`? And why 0.7in?

Comment: @egreg.  `\hbox` didn't typeset properly, whereas `\vbox` did.

Comment: It does for me.

Comment: @egreg Thanks. You are, of course, correct.  I tried again and it worked.  Must have typoed the first time.

Answer (score 7):

The standard `Puzzle` environment produces a centered object, because it executes `\PuzzlePre` and `\PuzzlePost`, defined as

```
\newcommand\PuzzlePre{%
    \par\noindent\mbox{}\hfill
}
\newcommand\PuzzlePost{%
    \hfill\null\par\noindent
}
```

The environment cannot be used in the argument of another command, because it relies on changing category codes.

You can exploit the `\PuzzlePre` and `\PuzzlePost` macros to define a `Puzzle*` environment that just produces a scalable box that you can then place at your pleasure. The leading optional argument is the scale factor (default 1 for no scaling).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cwpuzzle,graphicx}

\newsavebox{\puzzlebox}

\newenvironment{Puzzle*}[3][1]
 {%
  \def\PuzzlePre{\begin{lrbox}{\puzzlebox}}%
  \def\PuzzlePost{\end{lrbox}\scalebox{#1}{\usebox{\puzzlebox}}}%
  \Puzzle{#2}{#3}%
 }
 {\endPuzzle}

\begin{document}

x\begin{Puzzle*}[0.5]{5}{5}%
|[][Sf]S|[][Sf]A|[][Sf]T|[][Sf]O|[][Sf]R|.
|[][Sf]A|[][Sf]R|[][Sf]E|[][Sf]P|[][Sf]O|.
|[][Sf]T|[][Sf]E|[][Sf]N|[][Sf]E|[][Sf]T|.
|[][Sf]O|[][Sf]P|[][Sf]E|[][Sf]R|[][Sf]A|.
|[][Sf]R|[][Sf]O|[][Sf]T|[][Sf]A|[][Sf]S|.
\end{Puzzle*}y

\end{document}
```

I added x and y just to show what the reference point of the box will be.

[image]